# Filling an empty matrix with a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a 3195x71 matrix in Python using iterations and equations. The code is referenced below:-

```
##Creating an empty matrix
import numpy as np
CC_FINAL = np.empty((3195,71))
for i in range(3195):
    eB1_s = eB1[i]
    Ys = Y.iloc[i]
    Y_s = Ys.values.reshape(1,71)
    CC_s = np.dot(eB1_s,Y_s)
    CClist=CC_s
    CCdf=pd.DataFrame(CClist) 
    CC_final_demand_s=np.add(CC_s,HC,size=(1,71))
    print(CC_final_demand_s)
    Final_DD = np.concatenate((CC_FINAL,CC_final_demand_s))
print(Final_DD)
```

The equation `CC_final_demand_s=np.add(CC_s,HC,size=(1,71))` checks out and I get my desired output. The output is to look like this (upto 71 columns, 3195 times)

```
 0           1             2            3           4   \
1  5913403.203026  214.118854  15892.865306  5379.204602  333.111413   

          5          6            7          8          9          10  \
1  499.54388  27.436068  8302.752527  293.54779  30.622154  87.851813   

             11            12          13         14         15          16  \
1  10121.788307  38874.323567  120.792053  46.108922  20.592629  727.064092   

           17            18            19            20        21        22  \
1  7838.86962  30496.167176  92945.842897  40627.994136  4.506425  8.177975
```

But when I'm trying to combine the results from the equation above into the empty matrix, something does not seem to be working correct. I get the correct dimensions for `Final_DD` but the output is not right. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [formatting help](/help/formatting). Since you're new, please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre]. Welcome to SO!

Comment: "output is not right" is not a problem statement. Please be much more precise when asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

You start with `CC_FINAL = np.empty((3195,71))` and don't change it.  Did you look at its values?  I suspect you don't understand what `np.empty` does.

In the loop you do

```
Final_DD = np.concatenate((CC_FINAL,CC_final_demand_s))
```

That is joining the (3195,71) array with a (1,71) array producing a (3196,71), where most of the rows are garbage.  You do that again and again, without changing `CC_FINAL` or preserving `Final_DD`.  You just concatenate on a different `CC_final_demand_s`.  You are not "filling" `CC_FINAL` at all.

Work through the logic in more detail.  It may help for make much smaller arrays so you can actually look at the their values.